# Is there any detailed QFT-like description, at least tentatively, of Hawking radiation intensity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hawking-radiation

I wonder whether Hawking's derivation is purely heuristic, and in analogy with the Casimir effect case, whether a QFT based derivation of Hawking radiation intensity should depend on the coupling constants associated to the different interactions.

In particular, shouldn't be the particle-antiparticle fluctuation, often shown in Hawking radiation schemes, accompanied by some boson appearing as in usual Feynman diagrams?

Comment: My impression was that Hawking radiation was derived using QFT in curved spacetime. It's not at all like "a virtual particle pair pops out of nowhere and one escapes", that's just what science popularizers say.